# How to get textarea to take up 100% of remaining space?

Tags: html, css

I have a div with the following structure:

```
<div class = "card">
   <div class="menu">
      vertical menu here, pushed to the left
   </div>
   <div class ="content">
      <textarea> This should fill up everything in the card exept the menu div</textarea>
   </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get the 'textarea' to fill up the entire card while leaving the menu there.  My jsfiddle shows it a little too wide and pushed to below the card div for some reason:

http://jsfiddle.net/PTSkR/105/

How can I get that textarea to fill up the remaining card space?

Comment: and +1 because I like that menu :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/PTSkR/107/ ,

you can achieve it by using `float:left` for the menu, `float:right` for the textarea, and `CSS3 Calc` for calculating textarea's width, as in the example